# Android app screen resolution problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I wrote an android application targeting Android 2.2
Now, running it on Android 3.1 tablet it shows only half of the screen. I know its a famous problem and read the android's supporting multiple screens page.

below is my manifest file. let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="graphics.brick"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".BrickActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In yours template file change wrap_content to fill_parent like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Comment: my main.xml is<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
</LinearLayout>